# How can I change the source of an iframe when the user clicks on the browser back button?

Tags: javascript, iframe, drupal

Good day,

I have taken over a Drupal site that uses iframes for the main content area. I have a minor issue that I'd like to correct.

When a user clicks a link to a page that has a lot of content, then uses the browser's back button to navigate to the previous page, the old content appears, but the iframe's src does not change. I'm using some javascript to set the height of the page dynamically, so when the previous page has less content, there's a huge amount of empty space between the content and the footer.

Here's a diagram that hopefully illustrates what I'm working with:[image]

So upon returning to the previous page, via the browser back button, the footer is pushed way down below because the source has not changed, and therefore the page isn't rendered again.

I've not really used iframes because they aren't great to work with. I'm wondering, is there a way to force the source of the iframe to change when using the browser back button?